# Upload image created with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload, uploadify

How to upload image that is nested in img-element of the page (i.e. image was dynamically created with canvas2image jQuery plugin)? I have found uploadify plug-in, but don't know how to utilize it in this case. Should I create file input element with jQuery that will be used by uploadify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could send the pixel data ([obtained via `getImageData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/html/canvas/pixel_manipulation_with_canvas)) to your server via XHR and recreate the image on your server.

Comment: Thanks for idea. Can you point out how can I achieve this in ASP.NET?

Comment: @Fdr I don't know that language/framework sorry. But it should be as simple as writing an image using pixel data.